# Last occurrence of positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

If I have text in the following format:

```
string = "B. 1922, Naperville in the Chicago area; white; education: secondary; b/p."
```

I want to capture the "b/p" portion. I thought about using a positive lookbehind:

```
r"(?<=;)(.*)(?=\.)"
```

But, of course, this looks back to the ";" right after "area."

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/B4kt56/1%22Hi%22)

How would you all go about capturing everything at the end of the string up to the last occurrence of ";"? The desired output is “b/p”.

Comment: Try `([^; ]+)\.$` https://regex101.com/r/B4kt56/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *negated character class*:

```
(?<=;)\s*([^;.]*)(?=\.)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B4kt56/2)

- `[^;.]*` matches zero or more characters that are not `;` and `.`

Answer (score 4):

If you want the string after the last ";", you can have a simple non regex solution:

```
string.split(';')[-1]
```

I'm not sure what exactly is your pattern, I'll edit my answer if it doesn't help you.

Comment: If the OP _strictly_ wants just the `b/p.` part, then you'd probably need to strip the whitespace as well: `string.split(';')[-1].strip()`.

Answer (score 3):

In your case I don't think you need lookahead or lookbehind. Let the greedy quantifiers do their work:

```
.*;(.*)\.
```

Moreover, it's very performant compared to solutions that use lookahead/behind.

Comment: simple and efficient

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookbehind for the `;`, and gather the last four characters:

```
import re
string = "B. 1922, Naperville in the Chicago area; white; education: secondary; b/p."
print(re.findall('(?<=;\s)[\w\W]{4}$', string)[0])
```

Output:

```
b/p.
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you want to capture the string between the **last** `;`
and the first `.` after it (exclusive).

Try such regex:

```
;(?!.*?;)(.*?)\.
```

and read the content of the capturing group No 1.

Details:

- `;` - Match a semicolon.
- `(?!.*?;)` - Negative lookahead - nowhere further any semicolon can be found.
- `(.*?)` - This is what you want to capture. Note `?` after `*` -
  **reluctant** version.
- `\.` - The dot after "your" text.